# Help With Custom Commands on villigers with a custom item 1.15.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to get an emerald with a custom color added to it and have a villager sell the emerald. I was doing well getting both to spawn but when I tried to combine the two it didn't work. Can you tell me what I have done wrong?

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:{profession:farmer,level:2,type:plains},Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:acacia_boat,Count:1},sell:{id:emerald,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"\"aqua\"",Lore:["\"TOKENNNN\""]}}},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:acacia_boat,Count:1},buyB:{id:acacia_boat,Count:1},sell:{id:emerald,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"\"Token\",\" color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":true},{\"text\":\"ken\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":true}]\",},HideFlags:1}\""}}},maxUses:9999999}]}}
```

And the expanded command:

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~
{ 
   VillagerData:{ profession:farmer, level:2, type:plains },
   Offers:{ 
      Recipes:[ 
         { 
            buy:{ id:acacia_boat, Count:1 },
            sell:{ id:emerald, Count:1,
               tag:{ display:{ Name:"\"aqua\"", Lore:[ "\"TOKENNNN\"" ] } }
            },
            maxUses:9999999
         },
         { 
            buy:{ id:acacia_boat, Count:1 },
            buyB:{ id:acacia_boat, Count:1 },
            sell:{ id:emerald, Count:1,
               tag:{ display:{ Name:"\"Token\",\" color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":true},{\"text\":\"ken\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":true}]\",},HideFlags:1}\"" } }
            },
            maxUses:9999999
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

To specify the issue, it is only reading the "TOKEN" part of it and not the rest

Comment: You should try to get each part of the command working individually and only then put it all together.

Comment: I was able to spawn in the token itself and the villager to sell the emerald i just need it to sell the attributes of the emerald.

Comment: OK, then try the inner part on its own and then put it into the big command.

Comment: that is what i did but it broke when i did

Comment: I see a bunch of spaces that don't belong there, including `\" color\"`, which definitely breaks stuff, non-quoted IDs, NBT matching that is not exact (like `Count:1` instead of `Count:1b` in the `buy` tag), … What error messages did you get when you tried it? Some of them should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:{profession:farmer,level:2,type:plains},Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:acacia_boat, Count:1b},sell:{id:emerald,Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"\"aqua\"",Lore:["\"TOKENNNN\""]}}},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:acacia_boat, Count:1b},buyB:{id:acacia_boat, Count:1b},sell:{id:emerald,Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"[{\"text\":\"Token\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":true},{\"text\":\"ken\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":true}]"},HideFlags:1}},maxUses:9999999}]}}
```

Expanded:

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~
{
  VillagerData: {profession: farmer, level: 2, type: plains},
  Offers: {
    Recipes: [
      {
        buy: {id: acacia_boat, Count: 1b},
        sell: {
          id: emerald,
          Count: 1b,
          tag: {
            display: {
              Name: "\"aqua\"",
              Lore: ["\"TOKENNNN\""]
            }
          }
        },
        maxUses: 9999999
      },
      {
        buy: {id: acacia_boat, Count: 1b},
        buyB: {id:acacia_boat, Count: 1b},
        sell: {
          id: emerald,
          Count: 1b,
          tag: {
            display: {
              Name: "[{\"text\":\"Token\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":true},{\"text\":\"ken\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":true}]"
            },
            HideFlags: 1
          }
        },
        maxUses: 9999999
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The main issue was with your JSON text for the second offer. Yours was (unescaped):

```
"Token"," color":"aqua","italic":true},{"text":"ken","color":"aqua","italic":true}]",},HideFlags:1}"
```

Not only did you include the `HideFlags` NBT tag in the JSON text components, but there are missing brackets and an extra quote and space. The correct JSON is

```
[
  {
    "text": "Token",
    "color": "aqua",
    "italic": true
  },
  {
    "text": "ken",
    "color": "aqua",
    "italic": true
  }
]
```

Also, you should always include `b` or `B` after a byte tag (like in `Count`).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:{profession:farmer,level:2,type:plains},Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:acacia_boat, Count:1b},sell:{id:emerald,Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"\"aqua\"",Lore:["\"TOKENNNN\""]}}},maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:acacia_boat, Count:1b},buyB:{id:acacia_boat, Count:1b},sell:{id:emerald,Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"[{\"text\":\"Token\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":true},{\"text\":\"ken\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":true}]"},HideFlags:1}},maxUses:9999999}]}}`